# How to simulate Airplane mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

I'll be overseas and don't want to be racking up roaming or whatever other charges.  Typically I would use the Airplane mode, but I still want to be able to take photos that have the geo locations recorded.

So I want to know whether turning off Settings/Cellular/Cellular Data will take care of what I want (e.g. remove the chance that I'll be inadvertently charged for something)?  It says Cellular `Data`...does it mean I have to turn off Cellular Voice somewhere or does this do the trick?

Comment: Cellular data is exactly what it says. It does not turn off the voice (phone calls)

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do I do to turn off the phone calls?

Comment: In that case take out the SIM card.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove your SIM. Then there's no chance of incurring any cellular charges, as you won't be able to connect to any network, but wifi and GPS should still work. (If you have a CDMA phone with no SIM then you can't roam anyway.)

Comment: That is the ultimate way, but it does disables making calls as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, turning Cellular **Data** off will not disable calls. However, I do not really see a reason to also disable calls. As long as you do not make any calls yourself and do not answer any incoming ones, there won't be any roaming charges - even if your phone rings.

Alternatively you might want to talk to your mobile phone provider; these days they often offer very reasonable data and/or voice roaming packages.